How to show new iPadOS 18 tab bar inside navigation bar?
With the new iOS 18 tab bar, it now shows at the top to supposedly save space. But, I have my UITabBarController shown from a UINavigationController, so I have a navigation item at the top with a back button on the left, title in the middle, and another button on the right. My tab bar is showing directly underneath it. This does not save any space. Since my current tab will have the same title as what's shown in the navigation item, I would like my tab bar to show inside the navigation item instead of repeating the title.
What is the proper way to achieve this?
Thanks.
Current look:

Desired look:


The tab view should contain the navigation view, not the other way around. This is true in UIKit apps as well.
